# Grails many to many with 3 classes: sorting by the number of relationships

Tags: sorting, grails, many-to-many, grails-orm, transient

Let's say we have 3 domain classes: 2 classes related with each other through a 3rd class.

Ok, some code:

```
class A {
     String subject
     String description

     static hasMany = [cs: C]

     static transients = ['numberOfCs']

     Long getNumberOfCs() {
         return cs.size()
     }
}

class B {
     String title
}

class C {
     A objectA
     B objectB

     static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

Pretty clear? I hope so. This work perfectly with my domain.

You can see the transient property numberOfCs, which is used to calculate the number of C instances related to my A object. And it works just fine.

The problem: listing all my A objects, I want to sort them by the number of relationships with C objects, but the transient property numberOfCs cannot be used for the scope.

How can I handle the situation? How can I tell GORM to sort the As list by numberOfCs as it would be a regular (non transient) field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that Grails' criteria do support this, as you need both to select the A object itself and aggregate by a child objects (`C`). That means grouping by all the `A`'s fields, which is not done automatically.

If you only need some fields from A, you can group by them:

```
def instances = A.withCriteria {
  projections { 
    groupProperty('subject')
    count('cs', 'cCount')
  }
  order 'cCount'
}
```

otherwise you'll need to retrieve only `id`s and make a second query, like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583357/207791).

Another way is to use [derived properties](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#derivedProperties) like described [here](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/12/31/create-transients-using-formula-in-grails/) (not sure it will work though):

```
class A {
    static mapping = {
        numberOfCs formula: 'select count(*) from C where c.b_id = id'
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, the formula hasn't worked for me and I haven't tried the withCriteria. But I use the solution of retrieving the ids with 2 separated queries, as indicated in this answer you linked me. If you edit your answer to make it more visible to anyone, I can accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider your Problem GORM related but rather general Hibernate or even SQL related.

Take a look at the [HQL Docu](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) they are a lot of examples.

check the following HQL this pretty close what you are asking.

```
select mySortedAs from A mySortedAs left join mySortedAs.cs myCsOfA order by              
count(myCsOfA)
```

I think I saw somewhere that you also can do something like this myCsOfA.length or myCsOfA.size

Comment: Thank you, but I wasn't asking how to sort by count a simple query, but how to sort list results in a gsp with a transient field. Your answer is just a piece of what I was looking for. Look at the link reported by Victor to see the solution I applied.

Comment: The answer is GORM/Hibernate can't do what you are asking for. Hibernate is not aware of your transient field nor does it know what happens inside your method. Hibernate is only a ORM framework. the closes you can get is with a 1. formula, 2.right query 3. manual sort after retrieving.