# Using gorm to select and sort on subtable

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm working on a grails project and I have a domain class (Messages.groovy) that has:

```
static hasMany = [recipients:Recipient]
```

I'm trying to query for all messages belonging to an account and sorting on the number of recipients it has.

So far I'm totally lost, trying to look at the docs the only thing I've come up with is:

```
def query = {
    eq('account', account)
    projections {
        count "recipients"
    }
}
```

I'm probably way off but I'm not even sure how to google for this. I just need to get the message objects along with the count of recipients sorted by count of recipients.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583210/sort-by-association-count-in-grails

Comment: I was told I should be using criteria and projections to do this.

Comment: You would have better flexibility using HQL instead of Criteria. Moreover, if you do not know already, a Criteria gets converted to a hibernate query during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and understandable way to achieve this is by using a query and a map in the query(little verbose) but easily apprehended in comparison to a complex criteria.

```
def result = Message.executeQuery("select \
                                   new map(m as message, count(r) as countRec) \
                                   from Message as m \
                                   inner join m.recepients as r \
                                   where m.account = :account \
                                   group by m \
                                   order by count(r) desc", [account: account])

result.each{
    println it.message
    println it.countRec
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have this working with hql/sql but I'm being told I need to use criteria and projections to do this. I should hopefully get a solution today I will post a result when I get it.